# Non-monotonous DTS in output stream previous current changing to This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am having a file.txt with rather close snippets

```
file 'input.mp4'
inpoint 1.5402465510368346
outpoint 2.722609395980835
file 'input.mp4'
inpoint 3.192511146068573
outpoint 7.074568028450012
file 'input.mp4'
inpoint 7.851800565719604
outpoint 9.023683423995971
file 'input.mp4'
inpoint 10.054571752548219
outpoint 12.008032734394073
file 'input.mp4'
inpoint 18.70977670431137
outpoint 21.20993923664093
file 'input.mp4'
inpoint 24.51183382153511
outpoint 26.465287650823594
...
```

I concat them with

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i file.txt out.mp4
```

and I tried

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -safe 0 -f concat -i file.txt out.mp4
```

Yet I get

```
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2069, current: 2067; changing to 2070. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2070, current: 2067; changing to 2071. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2071, current: 2067; changing to 2072. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 00000178c50f8a80] Queue input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2758, current: 2756; changing to 2759. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 00000178c50f8a80] Queue input is backward in time
    Last message repeated 5 times
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7581, current: 7579; changing to 7582. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 00000178c50f8a80] Queue input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7582, current: 7579; changing to 7583. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 00000178c50f8a80] Queue input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7583, current: 7579; changing to 7584. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 00000178c50f8a80] Queue input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7584, current: 7579; changing to 7585. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 00000178c50f8a80] Queue input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7585, current: 7579; changing to 7586. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 00000178c50f8a80] Queue input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7586, current: 7579; changing to 7587. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 00000178c50f8a80] Queue input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7587, current: 7579; changing to 7588. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 00000178c50f8a80] Queue input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7588, current: 7579; changing to 7589. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7589, current: 7579; changing to 7590. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 00000178c50f8a80] Queue input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 00000178c514cc00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7590, current: 7579; changing to 7591. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 00000178c50f8a80] Queue input is backward in time
```

And the final file is cut at wrong places.

How to make the file.txt work?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The concat demuxer will select portions of the input outside the stated range if that portion is required for decoding purposes. These will cause a timestamp clash as well extra material in your output. You'll need to use the select filter to get rid of them.

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -segment_time_metadata 1 -i file.txt -vf select=concatdec_select -af aselect=concatdec_select,aresample=async=1 out.mp4
```

Comment: **select filter** documentation [at this link](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) 

Comment: Since this requires a re-encode, does it render the concat demuxer redundant? At that point would it be the same thing to just encode without using the concat demuxer?

Comment: You would have to feed all files individually as inputs with `-ss` and `-to` for each and then use concat filter. If it's a few files, manageable else it will get too tedious.

Comment: it also works with x11grab

Comment: I came across this answer, but I was hoping it'd basically say "this error is wrong" because I don't have any DTS audio tracks. Seems that this error messes with the video track though. It becomes very choppy when all I'm doing is swapping around track order.

Comment: dts refers to decoding timestamp, not the audio codec.