# Non-monotonous DTS in output stream after using ss

Tags: ffmpeg

I did

```
ffmpeg -i x.mp4  -ss 17 two.mp4
```

and now I try to do

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

with list.txt:

```
file 'one.mp4'
file 'two.mp4'
```

But when it starts processing `two.mp4` I get a whole bunch of these kinds of errors

> ```
> [mp4 @ 0x7fc4cf03de00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 373897,
> current: 371200; changing to 373898. This may result in incorrect timestamps in
> the output file.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This answer to a similar issue might be of help.
From: [Non-monotonous DTS in output stream previous current changing to This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021266/non-monotonous-dts-in-output-stream-previous-current-changing-to-this-may-result)

The concat demuxer will select portions of the input outside the stated range if that portion is required for decoding purposes. These will cause a timestamp clash as well extra material in your output. You'll need to use the select filter to get rid of them.

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -segment_time_metadata 1 -i file.txt -vf select=concatdec_select -af aselect=concatdec_select,aresample=async=1 out.mp4
```