# vsync flag usage in ffmpeg while filtering

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to apply a threshold to an input video with ffmpeg, but I observe the following warning emitted for every processed frame

```
[mp4 @ 0x56360181a200] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 182272, current: 182272; changing to 182273. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

where the previous and current are always 1 less than the value to which the DTS (Decoding Time Stamp) is changed

I have noticed this warning is emitted only if I set `-vsync passthrough` (which I changed from the original `-vsync 0` which is seen in many online examples).

```
# input.mp4 has resolution 790x790
ffmpeg -vsync passthrough  -i input.mp4  -f lavfi -i color=808080:s=790x790 -f lavfi -i color=black:s=790x790 -f lavfi -i color=white:s=790x790 -filter_complex '[0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v]threshold' -an -c:v h264_nvenc threshold.mp4
```

**Shall I leave the vsync flag set to the default** (auto or -1), or **is `-vsync passthrough` essential to guarantee the frames are displayed in the right order**? In that case, **how do I handle this warning**? Some other online examples I found of users experiencing this warning are different from mine, because in their case they are concatenating videos (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021266/non-monotonous-dts-in-output-stream-previous-current-changing-to-this-may-result), [2](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15468/non-monotonous-dts-on-concat-ffmpeg)

From the documentation on the `-vsync` flag, at the end, I see:

> With -map you can select from which stream the timestamps should be taken. You can leave either video or audio unchanged and sync the remaining stream(s) to the unchanged one

Maybe this warning should be handled with `-map`? But I don't know how.

Sidenote, I keep getting the deprecation warning asserting me to change `-vsync` for `-fps_mode`, however doing so breaks the command.

**FFPEG Version**:

commit `28ac2279adb860ea8b90d3073603912bf3eb6a83` from ffmpeg master branch

```
ffmpeg version N-108625-g28ac2279ad Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --enable-gpl --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --disable-static --enable-shared
libavutil      57. 39.101 / 57. 39.101
libavcodec     59. 50.100 / 59. 50.100
libavformat    59. 34.101 / 59. 34.101
libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
libavfilter     8. 49.101 /  8. 49.101
libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
```

**OS**

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: IMHO, you should only use non-default `vsync` (or `fps_mode` going forward) when you have a reason to do so. If you are gung-ho about using the passthrough mode. You should be able to avoid the warning by inserting `setpts` filter, generating strictly monotonically increasing pts of your liking.

Comment: I used `-vsync 0` because most of the examples in [the official ffmepg+h264_nvenc documentation from nvidia](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/) use it. There it is mentioned

> Use -vsync 0 option with decode to prevent FFmpeg from creating output YUV with duplicate and extra frames. 

I just use it to make sure no frames are dropped because in my actual application, I am encoding a live stream, and I thought this is the way to ensure that