# corrupted video after concat parts of captured RTSP stream with FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

**Target:** capture rtsp stream with sound from intercom camera and save it as 1hour duration video

---

URL for rtsp stream is updаting every 2 minutes, but i need to get parts with 1hour duration. So i see only solution to concatenate 2 minutes videos. It's required time between capturing stream parts to get response from server and reconnect with another url

---

First i tried `opencv`. It's not working with sound

---

Then i started using `ffmpeg`:

Capturing stream:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i <rtsp_url> 2min_part.mp4
```

[Concatenating](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate):

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i parts_list.txt -c copy concatenated_1.mp4
```

in stdout getting `Non-monotonous DTS in output stream`:

```
[mp4 @ 0x560c12d80bc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 57400952, current: 41462297; changing to 57400953. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x560c12d80bc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 57400953, current: 41462809; changing to 57400954. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x560c12d80bc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 57400954, current: 41463321; changing to 57400955. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
...
```

**After opening video in media players i see that from one second video is stopped, but sound is going on**. Interesting part that with every new opening this second (starting from video stops) changes

---

Then i tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53021506/15637940):

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -segment_time_metadata 1 -i parts_list.txt -vf select=concatdec_select -af aselect=concatdec_select,aresample=async=1 concatenated_2.mp4
```

No `Non-monotonous DTS` wаrnings, but video is **still corrupted** like first. Also this solution requires a lot of CPU while first concatenating method is very fast.

---

**Question**: How to do concatenating and get not corrupted video? May be i need to configure capturing options to simply use concatenating with `-c copy`?

[parts of videos and concatenated](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RWGXY94ShhhVxMnguh9MiFGyQNjVIZJZ?usp=share_link)

using `exiftool concatenated_1.mp4` i see that:

```
Duration                        : 1:17:44
Track Duration                  : 1:17:44
Media Duration                  : 0:53:59
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, fixing the timestamps (`-avoid_negative_ts make_zero`) and setting the same timebase (-video_track_timescale 90000) help to avoid `Non-monotonous DTS in output` errors in case of using the [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer). This command does the job without re-encoding (`-c copy`):

```
for f in Подъезд*.mp4; do
  num=${f##*_}
  num=${num%.*}
  num=$(printf "%02d" $num)
  ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i $f \
    -avoid_negative_ts make_zero \
    -video_track_timescale 90000 \
    -c copy \
    part_${num}.mp4
done
```

Then you can use concat demuxer (without any error):

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y \
  -f concat -safe 0 \
  -i <(for f in part*.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) \
  -c copy \
  output.mp4
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help. Still see `Non-monotonous DTS` while concatenating. Also tried `make_non_negative` and `disabled` values for `-avoid_negative_ts` option

Comment: Update ffmpeg. It's working on your dataset with a modern version of ffmpeg.

Comment: i built ffmpeg from source today

Comment: built [ffmpeg from source](https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2) `version N-109394-ga9d15d43eb`, then with `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` installed `version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1`. But it's not working. I did the same as you except `i <(for f in part*.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done)`. Can't use this, because by default files are not sorted as it needs for me with prefix "*_1", "*_2", "*_10". That's why i used `-i list_parts.txt`, but i'm not sure that it's really important

Comment: Could you please link me which version did you use?

Comment: Also tried `5.1.2`...

Comment: Ah, ok. For the test I took the first nine files. The fixing timestamps works for them. But a few of the remaining files have the different timebases. You can check it: `for f in Подъезд*.mp4; do ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries format=filename:stream=time_base -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 $f; done`. The updated answer works for all of them.

Comment: It works, thank you a lot! Probably i'm starting understand something... If you don't mind i can buy you a coffee (unfortunately, i can't do international transactions, but can do it using BTC) if you provide link in your profile